# How to best install v4l2loopback on Linux Mint?

Tags: kernel-modules, v4l2loopback, obs-studio

I am trying to create a virtual webcam from OBS(26.1.1) so I can feed it to Zoom.  I am Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon, version 4.8.6, Kernel 5.4.0-64-generic.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-utils
```

but v4l2loopback is not showing up as an option in zoom

I went to the v4l2loopback github page, where it suggested I should build it from scratch and install it into my kernel.  I tried to build from scratch and immediately ran into problems with the make command.

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/berggren/Downloads/v4l2loopback-main modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-64-generic'
make -C utils
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/berggren/Downloads/v4l2loopback-main/utils'
cc  -I..   v4l2loopback-ctl.c   -o v4l2loopback-ctl
v4l2loopback-ctl.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <sys/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: v4l2loopback-ctl] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/berggren/Downloads/v4l2loopback-main/utils'
make: *** [Makefile:85: utils/v4l2loopback-ctl] Error 2
```

I didn't go further because I wasn't sure I was going in the right direction with that.

Could someone explain the correct procedure for installing v4l2loopback?

Comment: Welcome, have you tried the dkms way : [v4l2loopback on github](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. installing `v4l2loopback-dkms` will install the modules on your system (at least: if all goes well), but it will not load the modules for you
2. so you need to manually load the module with something like `modprobe v4l2loopack`
3. in order for `zoom` to use the device, you will first have to attach OBS-studio to it.

you probably need to pass the `exlusive_caps=1` option when loading the module, in order for `zoom` to recognise it.